# HashMap<Integer, String> ClassCastException

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Не понял, в чём проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Консоль:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Я же ключи ставлю, а ключи это Integer. Зачем он их пытается кастовать в String?!

```
private HashMap<Integer, String> RanksList = new HashMap<>();

if (this.getConfig().contains("PlayerRank")) {
    this.RanksList = (HashMap) this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("PlayerRank").getValues(false);
} else {
    this.getConfig().set("PlayerRank.100", "\u00a7a\u00a7lНовичок\u00a7r");
    this.getConfig().set("PlayerRank.500", "\u00a7e\u00a7lОпытный\u00a7r");
    this.getConfig().set("PlayerRank.1500", "\u00a71\u00a7lВетеран\u00a7r");
    this.getConfig().set("PlayerRank.3000", "\u00a75\u00a7lМастер\u00a7r");
    this.getConfig().set("PlayerRank.4500", "\u00a7c\u00a7lЛегенда Зоны\u00a7r");
    this.RanksList = (HashMap) this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("PlayerRank").getValues(false);
}
```

Это часть моего кода из загрузки конфига плагина на сервер майнкрафта. Bukkit.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54032/discussion-on-question-by-prototype-tv-hashmapinteger-string-classcastexcep).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предположим, что метод `getValues` возвращает `Map<String, String>`:

```
private static Map<String, String> getValues()
{
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("abc", "def");
    return map;
}
```

Если некорректно с ним работать (с использованием raw-type вместо generics), то вполне возможна такая ситуация:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    HashMap<Integer, String> ranksList = (HashMap)getValues();
    for (int i : ranksList.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println("Key: " + i);
    }
}
```

Которая приведёт к

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Так как на самом деле в хэш-таблице в качестве ключей участвуют `String`, а сделать `Integer` из `String` простым приведением типа нельзя.

Если бы код был такой:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> ranksList = (HashMap<Integer, String>)getValues();
```

То была бы ошибка компиляции:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>` cannot be converted to `java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String>`

---

Можно предположить, что метод `getValues` возвращает просто `Map`, из-за чего уже и

```
 HashMap<Integer, String> ranksList = (HashMap<Integer, String>)getValues();
```

не спасёт ситуацию (код скомпилируется, но `ClassCastException`, конечно, никуда не денется), но это уже будет вина разработчиков метода `getValues`.

---

И, судя по новому скриншоту

[image: screenshot]

Метод `getValues` возвращает `Map<String, Object>`, который содержит в качестве ключей `String` и который не стоит пытаться кастовать к `Map<Integer, String>`, потому что ни тип ключей не совпадает, ни тип значений.

Если нельзя изменить возвращаемый `getValues` тип, то можно создать `Map<Integer, String>` на базе `Map<String, Object>`:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> ranksList = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> map = getValues();
for (String key : map.keySet())
{
    ranksList.put(Integer.parseInt(key), String.valueOf(map.get(key)));
}
```

Или с использованием Java 8:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> ranksList = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> map = getValues();
map.forEach((key, value) -> ranksList.put(Integer.parseInt(key), String.valueOf(value)));
```

Также не стоит забывать, что если какой-то из ключей в `map` не подходит под формат, принимаемый методом `Integer.parseInt`, то будет проброшено `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/82Q59yXIj3d5G2.png

Comment: @Prototype-TV вот то-то и оно: метод `getValues` возвращает хэш-таблицу, ключами в которой являются `String`. Сделать `Integer` из `String` простым приведением типов не получится.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Vm67BpYsD0zGb2 Решено.

Comment: @Prototype-TV добавил в свой ответ пару вариантов преобразования. Возможно, какой-то из них вас заинтересует. И если мой ответ вас устраивает, то не забудьте его отметить как правильный.

Comment: ваш вариант мне кажется более правильным, всё же возьму его. Но скажите, мой вариант со скриншота выше имеет недостатки?

Comment: @Prototype-TV итерация по `entrySet()` - это нормально. А вот недостатком является то, что вы не используете generics в `Map.Entry`. Из-за этого вам приходится приводить ключ к `String` вручную, что не есть хорошо. Нужно в данном случае использовать `Map.Entry<String, Object> entry :`

Comment: окей. Поправил у себя. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Всем спасибо.
Поправьте меня, если где то сделал лишние)

```
    if (this.getConfig().contains("PlayerRank")) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("PlayerRank").getValues(false).entrySet()) {
            this.RanksList.put(Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey()), String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
        }
    } else {
        this.getConfig().set("PlayerRank.100", "\u00a7a\u00a7lНовичок\u00a7r");
        this.getConfig().set("PlayerRank.500", "\u00a7e\u00a7lОпытный\u00a7r");
        this.getConfig().set("PlayerRank.1500", "\u00a71\u00a7lВетеран\u00a7r");
        this.getConfig().set("PlayerRank.3000", "\u00a75\u00a7lМастер\u00a7r");
        this.getConfig().set("PlayerRank.4500", "\u00a7c\u00a7lЛегенда Зоны\u00a7r");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("PlayerRank").getValues(false).entrySet()) {
            this.RanksList.put(Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey()), String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
        }
    }
```